# How to use unscoped on HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, model

I want to ignore default scope from the HABTM like I have 2 models **Email** and **Category** on which I want to use unscope. So far I have tried this

```
Category.unscoped do
  Email.where(:id=> 123).first.catgories
end
```

If I remove default scope from model **Category**, then email(with id=> 123 ) has two categories. But with using above method, where first I am unscoping category and then finding categories of the email is not working for me, as in a result I am getting only one category.

So, if anyone can help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you may try

    email = Email.where(:id=> 1322).first
    categories = email.categories

Comment: Could

Email.where(:id=> 1322).first.catgories.unscoped
return the correct result?

Comment: @lalameat, I have tried this, using this will give all the categories(following unscope), regardless they belong to email or not.

Comment: What did it return when you use your code in the question?

Comment: @lalameat, firstly it will load the email and then it will return all the category(with following query, SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
var1=""
Category.unscoped do
  var1=Email.where(:id=> 123).first.catgories.map{|a| a.id}
end

var1.inspect
```

It'll definitely work.

Comment: Using map has solved my problem. But if I don't use map, the problem still continue. So I am stilling looking for some good solution